# How to use tee command in the crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, tee

I put a job in crontab to run every 2 hours, also i want the log file of my bash output in a separate file.

**Input:**

```
0 0-23/2 * * * /tmp/sample.sh | tee /tmp/logfile_extract_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H').txt
```

**Output:**

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: `0-23/2` syntax could be replaced by `*/2` which is more standard.

Answer (score 3):

The percent (%) symbol is a special character in cron.    Escape the % signs.

```
0 0-23/2 * * * /tmp/sample.sh > /tmp/logfile_extract_$(date '+\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H').txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 3):

Perfectly good reason to want that. And you can totally use `tee` if you wanted to and still be able to capture output to `MAILTO`. Take this crontab for example

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILTO=someone@example.com
0 */2 * * * php /path/script.php | tee -a /path/log.$(date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d").txt
```

Note what Lars said and escape those percent symbols (`%`)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `tee` in a cron job. To redirect output you can do:

```
0 */2 * * * /tmp/sample.sh > /tmp/logfile_extract_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H').txt 2>&1
```

`tee` needs your tty to display output and there is no tty available with a cron.

As per `man tee`:

> The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a
>   copy in zero or more files.

Comment: The job is not running and i am getting the same error again in cron logs :
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Run `/tmp/sample.sh > /tmp/logfile_extract_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H').txt 2>&1` on command line first

Comment: cron's PATH is very limited. What is inside `sample.sh`

Comment: If i am simply using `0 */2 * * * /tmp/sample.sh` its working perfect.

Comment: Yes that will work but you will not be able to capture stdout/stderr in a file.

Comment: so using tee can i add that log part in my script itself ? Because in some case i have to run the script manually.

Comment: Yes, if you're running your script interactively then you can use `tee`. However while running from cron you can't use tee.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments above

```
/tmp/logfile_extract_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H').txt
```

IS the problem
1) is /bin/sh actually bash? I've seen OSes where its 'something more sh like' and thus the bash specific syntax might be throwing it.

```
0 */2 * * * /bin/bash -c '/tmp/sample.sh > /tmp/logfile_extract_$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H").txt 2>&1'
```

may work in this case.  Or you could consider backtick notation or a wrapper script called from cron that just does the

```
/tmp/sample.sh > /tmp/logfile_extract_$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H").txt 2>&1
```